# Statics problem with django docker nginx gunicorn

Tags: django, docker, nginx, static, gunicorn

I have a small problem with access to my django statics through nginx.
I serve the django server running in a docker, on a url with a location in nginx:

```
location /external/ {
  proxy_pass  http://external;
}
```

For static configuration in nginx i add:

```
location /external/static/ {
  autoindex on;
  alias /external/static/;
}
```

For the configuration of my statics on Django I set this code in the settings:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
STATIC_URL = '/' + PREFIX + 'static/'   ## -> with my config = /external/static/
```

In my Dockerfile I run my django server with gunicorn and I expose it through port 8000. When I access directly to the server with port 8000 (http://serveraddr.com:8000) I don't have statics problems but when I access it with nginx (https://serveraddr.com/external) I get a not found on my statics.

Help me please

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your static files are in static directory

```
location /external/static/ {
  autoindex on;
  alias /full/path/to/folder/static;
}
```

Comment: Yes I know but my nginx is in a docker and my django server in another one

Comment: did you map static volume, show us your docker-compose file

Comment: That's what I told myself I was going to add a volume for statics.

Comment: I add the volumes and if it works I add the solution in the forum.

Comment: As I said show us your docker-compose file to have https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example